# JavaScript returning NULL/Undefined when trying to get a data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get the values stored inside a data attribute called data-title, however JavaScript doesn't display the value I have stored inside it. Been trying to put the value inside alert for testing, but it doesn't work. The following is my piece of code. Thank you.

```
<select id='item_ID' onchange='changeValue();'>
    <option data-title="Title 1">1</option>
    <option data-title="Title 2">2</option>
    <option data-title="Title 3">3</option>
    <option data-title="Title 4">4</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeValue(){

    var option=document.getElementById('item_ID');
    alert(option.getAttribute('data-title'));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the `data-title` value from the currently-selected `option`, as your `select` element itself is lacking that attribute:

```
function changeValue(){
    var select = document.getElementById('item_ID'),
        option = select.getElementsByTagName('option')[select.selectedIndex];
    alert(option.getAttribute('data-title'));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer was correct, thanks so much, will accept it in a second. Hugs

Answer (score 3):

The select element doesn't have a data-title attribute.  The option elements do.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your select element doesn't have a data-title attribute. Only the option elements have them.

Here's a working example:

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var title = options[i].getAttribute("data-title");
    alert(title);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E49hm/

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean. My elements have a data-title as you can see above

Comment: @Jordan I wrote `<select>` and `<option>` but without the backticks, so StackOverflow whited it out. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You want: option.value

```
<select id='item_ID' onchange='changeValue();'>
    <option data-title="Title 1">1</option>
    <option data-title="Title 2">2</option>
    <option data-title="Title 3">3</option>
    <option data-title="Title 4">4</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeValue(){
    var option=document.getElementById('item_ID'); 
    console.log(option.value);
}
</script>
```